# Filtering Ethernet lines

Tags: pcb-design, ethernet, emc, layout, emi-filtering

I'm designing a product where we have an ethernet cable from a Raspberry Pi inside the machine going to a PCB with two RJ45 connectors on it placed at the back of the machine. This "routing" PCB today has no other components on it apart from the two RJ45 connectors, and two USB connectors for a similar routing function out of the machine.

When performing EMC tests we have noticed large emissions from the ethernet cable coming out from the machine, from this PCB. This has lead me to believe that we have noise from inside the machine coupling onto the ethernet cable between the RPi and the routing PCB, which is why I'm looking into adding some filtering components to this PCB, and also just improve the design overall.

Here's the schematic of the design: [image]

Here is what the PCB looks like today.

[image]

For your info, the RJ45 connector that goes to the outside of the machine is shielded and the shield is connected to the PCB ground. The RJ45 connector that connects to the RPi is not shielded.

My questions are:

1. For filtering I'm thinking of adding a CM choke, since I believe most noise should be CM noise. Does this make sense?
2. Reading up on how ethernet is constructed, it seems like I should add a CM choke on line 1 & 2 for TX and one on line 3 & 6 for RX. Is this correct, or should I add chokes on additional/different lines?
3. At the moment the ground plane of this PCB is not connected to chassi ground, nor any other ground in the machine. I suspect that this is not very good from an EMC perspective, and that I should add a connection to chassis ground, probably through something like a 100nF Y-capacitor. Am I correct in this assumption?

EDIT: Added schematic of the design

Comment: Draw a clear schematic of the board in question, the connection to the PI and the connection to what other equipment are present during testing. Show all earth points and power supplies. Indicate all ethernet magnetics also. Indicate where any cable shields are grounded or decoupled. Don't skimp on this; your words that attempt to describe it are just not sufficient (for instance, who but you know what lines 1 and 2 are?). This is why EEs use schematics. Is the whole thing surrounded by a metal box? Specifically what EMC tests were you doing? Cable emissions could mean radiated or conducted.

Comment: Also, [please take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) and note that none your previous questions you have asked have received formal acceptance of an answer. I know that all won't have received good answers but some have and, maybe you were not aware of this part of the process?

Comment: Ah, sorry, had missed that that was expected/required, sorry!